# 403 Forbidden Error, Ajax call only in Firefox

Tags: php, jquery

Below is my code, it's working fine on Chrome but Firefox is showing 403 forbidden error for the AJAX request on `save2.php` in my code. Also why is it taking so much time to load?

Scenario: form submitted to `preview.php` where a div is returned as the response. The returned div will convert into an image and send to `save2.php` which saves the image to the server.

```
$('.sharer').click(function(e){

        $(this).html("<img src='img/spinner.gif' style='pointer-events: none; cursor: default;'/>");


        e.preventDefault(); 
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          cache: false,
          url: this.href, // our preview file (preview.php)
          data: $("#myForm").serializeArray(), // all the fields in your form (use the form's ID)
          success: function (response) {

          $(".the-return").html(response);

             elem = $('.the-return');
             html2canvas(elem, {
             onrendered: function(canvas) {
             var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
             var output = encodeURIComponent(img);
             var Parameters = "image=" + output;
             var me = this;
             }
             }); //HTML2CANVAS

             $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "save2.php", // Only Firefox showing 403 forbidden
                data: Parameters,
                success: function (datas) {
                $(".sharer").html("<img src='img/share.png'/>");
                    //$(".imgs").html(datas);

                     FB.ui(
                       {
                         method: 'feed',
                         name: 'XXXX',
                         link: 'XXXX',
                         picture: 'XXXX/'+datas,
                         media: [{'type': 'image', width: '586', height: '586'}],
                         caption: 'XXXX',


                         //type: 'video',
                         description: 'XXXX',
                         message: 'Facebook Dialogs are easy!'
                       },
                       function(response) {
                         if (response && response.post_id) {

                         } else {

                         }
                       }
                     ); //Fb Sgare
                 }

                });





          } // success
          }); // ajax



}); // on click
```

Comment: this link shows the reason for 403 forbidden error generally, http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/1905/Why+am+I+seeing+a+403+Forbidden+error+message%3F#gs, just give it a try

Comment: no luck, data is posting and displaying but not returning as response

Comment: try using `async:false` for both ajax

Comment: Nothing, from firebug if i open save2.php to new tab, it shows forbidden, but directly entering url on new tab is opening the page

Comment: try changing folder permission, chmod -R 777 /path/to/save2

Comment: all files are in root preview.php and save2.php, this happening in firefox only, not in chrome nor IE